# Using split(): method in Python 3 to get multiple inputs

Tags: python-3.x, input, split

I am working on a project where I need to implement code that will ask the user for multiple data inputs for the following fields for an employee directory: Last name, first name, employee number, and pay rate.

Answer (score 0):

That's example code which presents acquiring data from user input and splitting it (by space):

```
user_input = input("enter last name, first name, employee number, and pay rate: ")

a = user_input.split()

print (a[0]) # last name
print (a[1]) # first name
print (a[2]) # employee number
print (a[3]) # pay rate
```

You can obviously use other delimiter, passing it as a first argument to a split method.

Comment: now would using an if/else function after asking the user if they want to add another employee would work right? Lastly, would the same code above work for a search function so the user can search the directory by either: last name, first name, and employee number or just the pay rate.